# How to run php script on localhost stored on another server

Tags: php, apache, server

I want to run php script from another server on localhost I tried `include "http://example.com/settings/aiacacc.php";` but I'm getting an error.

```
 include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

How can I enable `include` from another server using `php.ini` file. I know it is not a good practice but my application is going run on localhost only. i don't want this setting to be disabled.
I want to return a php script from another server and then execute this script on my localhost

Comment: the url `http://example.com/settings/aiacacc.php` does return a PHP script or the compiled version of the file?

Comment: It returns a PHP script

Comment: `// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`

Answer (score 3):

Go to your `php.ini` file and edit it to switch on the allow_url_include setting:

```
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

Alternatively use the code below in your php file

```
ini_set('allow_url_include', 'On');
```

Comment: I want it to return a PHP script and execute this script on my localhost

Answer (score 2):

In php.ini:

```
allow_url_include=1
```

Comment: I want it to return a PHP script and execute this script on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above. you want to return some PHP code from another server and execute it on the localhost. For that the first step is to edit your `php.ini` file and add this line `allow_url_include = On` and secondly the php script that you want to return from another server should not have `.php` extension instead It should be saved as a simple text file with `.txt` extension